# Call to a member function fails() on array on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Iam just trying to validate some POST datas.

```
Route::post('/', function(){

$data = ['url' => request('url')];
$validation = Validator::make($data, ['url' => 'required|url'])->validate();

if($validation->fails())
{
    $dd('failed');
}
```

I don't understand why It doesn't work, can you help me please ?

Comment: It's `dd('failed');`. Remove the `$`.

Comment: `->validate()` returns an `array`. You can't call `{array}->fails()`, as `array` doesn't have that method. I think you can just call `$validator = Validator::make(...);`, then `if($validator->fails()){ ... }`

Comment: thank you for answer. Can you tell how I can do ? I am learning Laravel and PHP its very complicated

Comment: Re-read my comment. I just told you what you can try... Remove the `->validate()`.

Comment: ok tim lewis, thank you. how can I thank you I dont find the green flag

Comment: I'll add it as an actual answer. I posted as a comment, and you can't accept those. Give me a sec.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is due to the return type of `->validate()`. This will return an `array`, so `$validation` will be an `array` instead of a `Validator` instance, and you can't call `->fails()` on an `array`. To solve this, simply omit `->validate()`:

```
$validation = Validator::make($data, ['url' => 'required|url']);
if($validation->fails()){
  dd("Failed");
}
```

Sidenote; watch your syntax. `$dd()` is not a valid call.

Comment: `->validate()` will return an `array`,if it was not failed;otherwise it throw `exception`

Comment: @Md.Amirozzaman Right; thanks for the clarification. Either way, `->validate()->fails()` (either directly chained or via variable assignment) is not valid in either case :)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `validate` method provided by the **`Illuminate\Http\Request`** object directly as follow

```
$request->validate([
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'author.name' => 'required',
    'author.description' => 'required',
]);
//if fails code after this line will not be executed
```

This validation will auto redirected to back.This was default validation by laravel. If it not fails,it will continue with executing.

**Manually**

Now you can implement manually and redirect as your requirment.

```
use Validator;

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
                'body' => 'required',
            ]);

    //checks your validation and redirect as you want

    if ($validator->fails()) {
          return redirect('where/ever/you/want')
                         ->withErrors($validator)
                         ->withInput();
     }
```

Again you can default redirection,by calling `validate()` method

```
Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
])->validate();
```

If you call `validate` method it will redirect as default laravel.

> **dd()** is a method,short version of **`die and dump`**

**Useful link:**

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L312

Comment: @Julien Rns Neo check this answer,how `validator` works!before use `validation`